# Why do I get bounty emails when I'm supposedly not subscribed to emails?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, email

I checked the email I used for my Gravatar (the autogen image was cooler than the one that matches my OpenID), and I was surprised to find an automated Stack Overflow notifying me about a bounty I posted.

It told me I could opt out of these notifications, which I found odd because I wasn't aware I ever opted in to them. A study of my user profile shows a checkbox for "I'd like email notifications of activity on my questions and answers", which I have never toggled.

I find the on-site notification envelope to be far more useful, so I thought it less-than-optimal to use email notifications.

Why did I receive the email even with that setting turned off?

Comment: I suppose @Kop did it because it makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounty questions are automatic opt-in for email flag.

> We are also turning on this flag for
> **users who have a bounty question in
> play**. We want to make sure users have
> at least one day of email warning
> before their question bounty expires,
> so they remember to check for an
> answer and accept one, if they want to
> avoid the auto-accept that kicks in
> for the highest scored answer (minimum
> of 2 score required).

ref: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/now-showing-email-notifications/

Comment: I see. Curiosity... does this mean that even if I unsubscribe through the email, I'll simply be opted in again?

Comment: @ccomet, I couldn't find specific info about that, but if you set bounty on another question, you become **the user with a bounty question** again, so I guess it will be.

Comment: Satisfactory to me, then. I don't particularly mind the emails, but I was surprised. I'd accept your answer immediately but I want to leave the question open for a bit just in case some extra light is shed. Thanks, S.Mark.

Comment: @ccomet, no worries, just leave it open.

Answer (score 3):

Starting a bounty is an implicit opt-in to the bounty notification emails.

Otherwise, we get far too many complaints about "gee, you didn't *tell* me I had to select an answer before the bounty closed!"

Comment: Alright, well, that makes good sense. So, in the interest of not messing with the default settings which have good reasoning, is there anything I as a user can do, after starting a bounty, to opt out before the email is sent? No worries if I can't, but it'll be a nice thing to know.