# Allow multiple e-mail notification preferences on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, notifications, email

It looks like e-mail notification on Area 51 is an all-or-nothing option. I'd rather have multiple notification preferences.

For example, when a proposal is in commitment phase I don't care about the daily notifications that new people have committed to it. But I don't want to unsubscribe from all e-mail from Area 51 because I'd like a notification if the proposal gets accepted and makes it into beta.

Comment: meh, I don't need e-mail notifications, I am there like all day long refreshing

Answer (score 1):

I think phase-change emails are sent regardless of your settings. I don't recall opting into anything at Area 51, but I received emails for when Gaming and Game Development entered the commitment phase. I don't receive any other Area 51 emails, so I haven't gotten anything regarding who is committing or new questions or whathaveyou.

Comment: if that's the case then the messages are misleading. the unsubscribe link at the end of each e-mail says "unsubscribe from all Area 51 e-mail", and clicking on it brings you to a page that says "You are now unsubscribed from all Area 51 e-mail"

Comment: It's entirely possible that these are re-subscribed, not unlike [bounty emails](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51769/why-do-i-get-bounty-emails-when-im-supposedly-not-subscribed-to-emails) are, @Kip. Very much misleading, but in this case I think it is actually for the better, even if unwarranted.

Comment: That said, I think the safest way to try and ensure that you are opted back into phase-change emails is to uncommit and then commit.